# Заполнение БД и перенос на хостинг Asp Net Core with Entity Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Приложение asp net core с entity core. Само приложение будет представлять данные из БД. Юзеры ничего записывать туда не будут.

1. Можно ли заполнять БД вручную через ms sql management studio или через созданный scaffolding контроллер для entity прямо во время работы приложения?
2. Можно ли будет перенести заполненную на локалхосте БД на хостинг, просто изменив строку подключения и загрузить БД на хостинг?
3. Если я изменю БД и создам миграцию, на хостинг надо будет перезалить скопилированное приложение и отдельно перезалить БД? Или она сама изменится, увидев миграцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Можете заполнять вручную через SSMS, можно через методы контроллера, передавая нужные параметры (если вы собираетесь сделать некое подобие админ. панели, хотя конечно можно и напрямую методы контроллера через GET запрос вызывать, передавая нужные параметры)
2. Да, через SSMS можете сделать полный бэкап готовой БД, восстановить на хостинге и прописать нужную строку подключения.
3. Если у вас включено авто применение миграций, то после обновления сервера проект при первой компиляции (первом обращении к серверу) сам обновить модель БД до последней. Если нет, то можете выполнить команду Update-Database (указав нужную строку подключения).

Comment: Понял. А, то есть я могу с приложением развернутом на локалхосте, через консоль NuGet обращатся к ДБ которая на сервере находится?
Просто не могу найти информацию, как делать миграцию в БД которая уже на сервере

Comment: Да, именно так. В строке подключения прописан коннект к удаленной БД и вы просто применяете миграцию через Update-Database.